# rails: using associated model's columns in :where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure what's going on here. I have a scope I'm trying to create that works with my association:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end

create_table :products do |t|
   t.string  :name
   t.decimal :price
   t.decimal :cost_per_unit
   t.integer :user_id
end

create_table :subscriptions do |t|
   t.string  :name
   t.decimal :price
   t.decimal :cost_per_unit
   t.integer :subscriber_id
   t.integer :subscribable_id
   t.string  :subscribable_type
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.lower_prices
      Product.includes(:subscriptions).
      where("products.price < subscriptions.price OR products.cost_per_unit < subscriptions.cost_per_unit" )
  end
end
```

I'm trying to compare the lower price of the Product to the Subscription but this gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Pages#subscribed_products

PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subscriptions"
LINE 1: ...  WHERE (user_id != 2) AND (products.price < subscripti...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"  WHERE (user_id != 2) AND (products.price < subscriptions.price OR products.cost_per_unit < subscriptions.cost_per_unit)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah forgot it, thanks.

Comment: I do not see the associated model subscriptions in the query are you sure you have correct model names

Comment: Is there actually a subscriptions table, or is this a polymorphic thing with a different underlying model?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah this is a polymorphic association. I will edit my quiestion to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `includes` method doesn't do exactly what you think.  Substitute `joins` for `includes` and it should Do What You Mean:

```
Product.joins(:subscriptions).
      where("products.price < subscriptions.price OR products.cost_per_unit < subscriptions.cost_per_unit" )
```

or perhaps:

```
Product.includes(:subscriptions).joins(:subscriptions).
      where("products.price < subscriptions.price OR products.cost_per_unit < subscriptions.cost_per_unit" )
```

`joins` translates to a `JOIN` in the resulting SQL query, so you can perform WHERE clauses on the joined table.  `include` just asks Active Record to perform another query to select all the related records in the given table.  If you do both together, Active Record creates a (rather long) all-in-one that both joins the two tables and uses the results to create both sets of objects.

Comment: I think this whole time it wasn't working because a period `.` was missing! I feel dumb. Thank you sir!